# Python Gurobi: Output MIPGap, Runtime and solving details before optimization stops

Tags: python, output, gurobi

I am using Gurobi to solve a MIP problem, and I want to see how its MIPGap changes with respect to the Runtime. Is there any efficient way to collect these two information? The callback code does not provide MIPGap, and I don't know how to retrieve this attribute before the model terminates (get optimal solution).

Also, how could we output the MIP solving details (how it gets around the perceived non-convexity etc.) after it completes preprocessing?

Below are the codes that I am currently applying for gap and runtime:

```py
def mycallback(m, where):
    if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        time=m.cbGet(GRB.Callback.RUNTIME);
        a=m.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIPSOL_OBJBST);
        b=m.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIPSOL_OBJBND);
        gap=(b-a)/abs(a)*100;

model.optimize(mycallback)
```

Thank you very much!

Best,
Grace

Comment: Could you provide some code, what have you tried so far. Also if there is any error, post that too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I have just added the codes and another question into my post (output MIP solving details after preprocessing).